# Removing lines of files from a list matching patterns from another list

Tags: python

I have a list of files and a list of patterns like that :

```
fileList=glob.glob("*undex*fna")

barList=list(barcodes.values())

for i, j in zip (sorted(fileList), barList):
        print(i,j)

The original list : <type 'list'>
('bc1001_5p_test_undex.fna', 'CACTCGACTCTCGCGT')
('bc1002_5p_test_undex.fna', 'ACACTAGATCGCGTGT')
('bc1003_5p_test_undex.fna', 'ACACATCTCGTGAGAG')
('bc1004_5p_test_undex.fna', 'CACATATCAGAGTGCG')
('bc1005_5p_test_undex.fna', 'CATATATATCAGCTGT')
('bc1006_5p_test_undex.fna', 'ACACACAGACTGTGAG')
('bc1008_5p_test_undex.fna', 'ACAGTCGAGCGCTGCG')
('bc1012_5p_test_undex.fna', 'CACGCACACACGCGCG')
```

All the files `*fna` have that format ( thousands of lines for each file) :

```
head -n 2 bc1001_5p_test_undex.fna


>m64071_201130_104452/590189/ccs CACGCACACACGCGCGTGGATTGATATGTAATACGACTCACTATAGAGAGCTAATCTAAGCGAAAAAAATAGACATTTGAAAGCAAAAGCGTA
>m64071_201130_104452/590191/ccs AACACATCTCGTGAGAGTGGATTGATATGTAATACGACTCACTATAGGCAAAACCAATAAGCATATATACAACTATATATCGAGAGAGATAATATCATATAATATGG
and so on ..
```

I need to remove the full lines of the `*fna` files, where the patterns are found. But, the trick is : for example, I look at the first pattern `CACTCGACTCTCGCGT`. I have to remove the lines of the `*fna` files, where that pattern is found, but not in the first file `bc1001_5p_test_undex` (actually, the first pattern is "associated" with the first file, the second pattern is associated with the second file and so on..). Same trick for the second pattern : I have to remove the lines in all the files (except the second file) where the pattern `ACACTAGATCGCGTGT` is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the new codes in a list and display the value only if the code is not in the list

```
fileList=glob.glob("*undex*fna")
codes = []
barList=list(barcodes.values())

for i, j in zip (sorted(fileList), barList):
        if j not in codes:
            codes.append(j)
            print(i,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not test this, but I hope this will get you somewhere:

```py
file_list=glob.glob("*undex*fna")

bar_list=list(barcodes.values())

for file_name, bar_code in zip(sorted(file_list), bar_list):
    codes_to_remove = [code for code in bar_list if code != bar_code]
    new_file_content = list()
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file_handle:
        for line in file_handle.readlines():
            if any((code for code in codes_to_remove if code in line)):
                # found code in line, do not copy it
                pass
            else:
                new_file_content.append(line)
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file_handle:
        file_handle.writelines(new_file_content)
```

`[code for code in bar_list if code != bar_code]` makes list of all the barcodes except the one associated with the filename.
Simpler version `[x for x in bar_list]` would create list of all the barcodes - if you are not familiar with this syntax read about list comprehensions.
There are many ways to edit existing file but overwriting it with new content is the easiest so I have chosen to open the file and save all lines without matching bar codes and then opening file once again to override it with new content.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, it works for two files but not for the others : when I check `len(new_file_content)` , I get `1 20564 1 1 1 16280 1` . I check in `awk` and it is OK for the files with 20564 and 16280 LINES but I dont understand why that did not give the good result for the others..

Comment: syntax `line in <something>` looks for any match of a string, if what you want is just the beggining of a string this should be done with `if line.startswith(<somethinf>)` but this requires line splitting in this case because we have `>m64071_201130_104452/590189/ccs CACGCACACACGCGCGTGGATTGA...` so the line does not start with bar code

Comment: I only needed to ordered the values of my dictionnary, with `od=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(barcodes.items()))`
`bar_list=list(od.values())` , to get the good combinations